# Wordpress custom query failing

Tags: mysql, wordpress, admin

I'm creating a theme, with an admin page. In the admin page function, I have this line:

```
$result1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name) 
or die(mysql_error()."wrong");
```

In the admin page, "wrong" is printed. If I comment this line, everything works fine, except that I can't get those values. Before that, I also have this line:

```
$wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ".$table_name." (
    id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    url varchar (1023) NOT NULL,
    title varchar(511) NOT NULL,
    postpage varchar(511),
    link varchar(1023),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
)") or die(mysql_error());
```

It works fine. I've tried everything, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `or die()`, use `$wpdb->print_error();` to print any errors that may have occurred with the last query. So change

```
$result1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name) 
or die(mysql_error()."wrong");
```

to

```
$result1 = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM ".$table_name);
$wpdb->print_error();
```

See [the codex entry for the **wpdb** class](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_Generic_Results) for further reference.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't have time to try it, but I will do it now and keep You posted.

Comment: I got this error: WordPress database error: []
SELECT id, title, url, postpage, link FROM wp_kd_slideshow